# After alter the configuration of magento still product page connect to old database config

Tags: database, magento, caching, config, tmp

I recently add an new server for mysql, and moved magento database to new server.

I Restore database to new mysql and alter the configuration (in Web server) in app/etc/local.xml file

Removed cache, Magento admin panel > System > Cache management And deleting the contents of the var/cache and var/session folders inside Magento installation directory.

Now, Problem is, all of magento connect to new database connection Except product pages.
Because than i stop old mysql service only product page show connection lost.

I think, there is an other cached configuration file, maybe!

Comment: Are you definitely using `file` for cache save, and not APC or memcached?

Comment: We don't use any other type of cache. like memcached, etc...

Comment: Search your configuration files for for the following strings: `<catalog_read>` `<catalog_write>` `<connection>`